# Polymorphism through boost shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, polymorphism

I have a class hierarchy where one abstract parent (A) class has two children (B and C).

The whole point of these classes is to return a boost::shared_ptr which refers to another class hirarchy. The object being returned is initialising a data member. Other is the parent class of OtherB and OtherC.

```
//A.h
class A{
public:
    virtual boost::shared_ptr<Other> getMemManagedPolyObject();

private:
};

//B.cpp

boost::shared_ptr<Other> B::getMemManagedPolyObject(){
    return boost::shared_ptr<Other>(new OtherB());
}

//C.cpp
boost::shared_ptr<Other> C::getMemManagedPolyObject(){
    return boost::shared_ptr<Other>(new OtherC());
}
```

but I get errors suggesting I cannot do this. How can I get around the limitation to implement the same behaviour?

Comment: `return boost::shared_ptr<Other>(new OtherB);`

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/Tef2ou).

Comment: @KerrekSB could this be because you used std::shared_ptr and I used boost?

Comment: @user997112: I doubt it. The two are *very* similar.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed something of `OtherB` and `OtherC`, but I've had similar problems with `std::shared_ptr`, if the class being instantiated has a private destructor (which is often a good design decision).  You can work around this by explicitly casting the results of the `new` to `Other*` before passing it to `boost::shared_ptr<Other>`.